# How to download programmatically a folder from samba?

Tags: ios, samba

I am just working on a project in which I need to download some audio files from samba server, How can I do it? I have googled but couldn't find anything.

link: smb:\192.189.1.56\Sound\elementary_sound.mp3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iOS has no support for the SMB protocol by default.
However, it's well-documented by Microsoft and you can try any kind of its implementations like this https://sourceforge.net/projects/smb4ios/

But I'll give you a bet that any SMB implementation for iOS will not give you full feature support.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Made Pod with TOSMBClient and it works for me...